# Foldable and Monoid types

Tags: haskell, types, monoids, foldable

I'm trying to write functions that add and multiply all elements in a list using monoids and Foldable. I've set up some code that I think works:

```
data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor Rose where
    fmap f rose@(a:>b) = (f a :> map (fmap f) b) 

class Monoid a where
    mempty ::           a
    (<>)   :: a -> a -> a

instance Monoid [a] where
    mempty = []
    (<>)   = (++)

newtype Sum     a = Sum     { unSum     :: a } deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype Product a = Product { unProduct :: a } deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Num a => Monoid (Sum a) where
    mempty           = Sum 0
    Sum n1 <> Sum n2 = Sum (n1 + n2)

instance Num a => Monoid (Product a) where
    mempty                   = Product 1
    Product n1 <> Product n2 = Product (n1 * n2)

class Functor f => Foldable f where
    fold    :: Monoid m =>             f m -> m
    foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
    foldMap f a = fold (fmap f a)

instance Foldable [] where
    fold = foldr (<>) mempty

instance Foldable Rose where
    fold (a:>[]) = a <> mempty
    fold (a:>b)  = a <> (fold (map fold b))
```

And then after having defined the different Foldable instances and the Sum and Product types I want to define two functions that add respectively multiply the elements in a datastructure, but this gives errors which I do not know how to interpret, I must admit that I it was more guess work than actual logic so a thorough explanation of your answer would be welcome.

```
fsum, fproduct :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a
fsum b     = foldMap Sum b
fproduct b = foldMap Product b
```

Error:

```
Assignment3.hs:68:14: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Sum a
    * In the expression: foldMap Sum b
      In an equation for `fsum': fsum b = foldMap Sum b
    * Relevant bindings include
        b :: f a (bound at Assignment3.hs:68:6)
        fsum :: f a -> a (bound at Assignment3.hs:68:1)
   |
68 | fsum b     = foldMap Sum b
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Assignment3.hs:69:14: error:
    * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Product a
    * In the expression: foldMap Product b
      In an equation for `fproduct': fproduct b = foldMap Product b
    * Relevant bindings include
        b :: f a (bound at Assignment3.hs:69:10)
        fproduct :: f a -> a (bound at Assignment3.hs:69:1)
   |
69 | fproduct b = foldMap Product b
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You need to add a `unSum` and `unProduct` as post-processing step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `Sum` (or `Product`) in the `foldMap`, you will first *map* the items in the `Foldable` to `Sum`s (or `Product`s). Therefore the result of `fsum` will - like you defined it - be a `Sum a`, not an `a`:

```
fsum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> Sum a
fsum b = foldMap Sum b
```

In order to retrieve the value that is wrapped in the `Sum` constructor, you can fetch it with the `unSum :: Sum a -> a` getter:

```
fsum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a
fsum b = unSum (foldMap Sum b)
```

or after an *eta-reduction*:

```
fsum :: (Foldable f, Num a) => f a -> a
fsum = unSum . foldMap Sum
```

The same should happen for a `Product`.